# LocatorPane, selecting multiple Locators

Tags: graphics, gui-construction

Consider the following snippet

```
  pts = RandomReal[1, {3, 2}]
  g = Graphics[{Polygon[Dynamic[pts]]}, PlotRegion -> {{0, 0}, {2, 2}}];
  Panel[LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], g]]
```

I would like to be able to drag the triangle as a whole. I found none and assume this has to be added via code, i.e. `EventHandler` but found no examples of this.

**Question: How can I select, and act upon multiple locators, i.e. drag, scale, apply a transformation to the points?**

Comment: Not clear what you want: already you can move any of the triangle's vertices by dragging its locator. Do you want to drag the entire triangle at once?

Comment: Yes. In the program I have, there are several shapes. I want to select one and drag all at once. Doing it per locator would change the area, that would be a problem in the prog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. In this example I've used one list of points for the vertices of the two shapes. The inner `EventHandler` sets the flag `drag` which indicates which shape should be moved. The outer `EventHandler` actually moves the shape. Releasing the mouse resets `drag` to 0 again. I'm using `PassEventsDown -> True` in the outer event handlers to make sure that the mouse events are handed over from outer to the inner event handlers.

```
DynamicModule[{pts, range, gr, drag, pts0},
 pts = RandomReal[1, {7, 2}];
 range = {Span[1, 4], Span[5, 7]};
 gr = {{Red, Polygon[Dynamic[pts[[range[[1]]]]]]},
   {Blue, Polygon[Dynamic[pts[[range[[2]]]]]]}};
 drag = 0;

 Panel[LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],
   EventHandler[
    Graphics[
     EventHandler[gr[[#]],
        {"MouseDown" :> (drag = #; 
          pts0 = # - MousePosition["Graphics"] & /@ pts[[range[[#]]]])}
        ] & /@ {1, 2}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}],
    {"MouseDragged" :> 
      If[drag > 0, pts[[range[[drag]]]] = # + MousePosition["Graphics"] & /@ pts0],
     "MouseUp" :> (drag = 0)},
    PassEventsDown -> True]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is an example for "The Book". ;-)

Comment: When the polygons are positioned 'on top' of each other it is no longer possible to select and/or modify a locator. Is there a way around this? - I can make a new question if you like.

Comment: Played around with PassEventsDown and that did the trick, to my relief.