# LocatorPane and multiple EventHandlers, PassEventsDown option

Tags: graphics, programming, dynamic

Consider the following piece of code from Heike as an ( accepted ) answer on [LocatorPane, selecting multiple Locators](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6008/locatorpane-selecting-multiple-locators) - Basically the code implements dragging polygons on a LocatorPane.

```
 DynamicModule[{pts, range, gr, drag, pts0},
  pts = RandomReal[1, {7, 2}];
  range = {1 ;; 4, 5 ;; 7};
  gr = {{Red,  Polygon @ Dynamic @ pts[[ range[[1]] ]]},
        {Blue, Polygon @ Dynamic @ pts[[ range[[2]] ]]}};
  drag = 0;

  Panel[LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],
    EventHandler[
     Graphics[
      EventHandler[gr[[#1]],
         {"MouseDown" :>
           (drag = #; pts0 = # - MousePosition["Graphics"] & /@ pts[[ range[[#]] ]])}
      ] & /@ {1, 2}, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}],
     {"MouseDragged" :> 
       If[drag > 0, pts[[range[[drag]]]] = # + MousePosition["Graphics"] & /@ pts0],
      "MouseUp" :> (drag = 0)},
     PassEventsDown -> True
    ]
  ]]
 ]
```

If you run this code you'll notice that when a locator's position is on another polygon the locator does not work anymore.

**Question: How can the code above be changed so that a click on a locator always works? Why was it necessary to use two two EventHandlers, and what is a good rule to decide on wether to use the PassEventsDown option?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code does what you want. It requires that you press <kbd>shift</kbd> to move a locator that is being overlapped by a polygon, instead of moving that polygon.

```
DynamicModule[{pts, range, gr, drag, pts0}, 
 pts = RandomReal[1, {7, 2}];
 range = {Span[1, 4], Span[5, 7]};
 gr = {{Red, Polygon[Dynamic[pts[[range[[1]]]]]]}, {Blue, 
    Polygon[Dynamic[pts[[range[[2]]]]]]}};
 drag = 0;
 Panel[
  LocatorPane[
   Dynamic[pts],
   EventHandler[
    Graphics[
     EventHandler[
        gr[[#]],
        {
         "MouseDown" :> (drag = # Boole[¬CurrentValue["ShiftKey"]];
           pts0 = # - MousePosition["Graphics"] & /@ pts[[range[[#]]]])
         },
        PassEventsDown -> True
        ] & /@ {1, 2},
     PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}
     ],
    {
     "MouseDragged" :> 
      If[drag > 0, 
       pts[[range[[drag]]]] = # + MousePosition["Graphics"] & /@ pts0],
     "MouseUp" :> (drag = 0)
     },
    PassEventsDown -> True
    ], Enabled -> Dynamic[drag == 0]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'll first explain the causes of the unwanted behavior and then explain my solution.

At the base of the problem lies the fact that `LocatorPane` needs to get its own events, the clicks on the pane that (re)set the position of the locators. The 3 (not 2, if you look closely) `EventHandler`s get priority above the `LocatorPane` when you click in their elements. If you don't do a `PassEventsDown->True` `LocatorPane` won't see the event at all. It'll be eaten up by the handler. However, if you would pass down the event to the `LocatorPane` it would set a new position for the locator while at the same time the polygon is being dragged. You get a very erratic result.

My solution consists of the following:

1. Pass the events to `LocatorPane` by setting `PassEventsDown->True` in the deepest event handlers
2. If we have a dragging event, disable the `LocaterPane` using the option setting `Enabled -> Dynamic[drag == 0]`
3. Enable locator actions on overlapped locators by multiplying the `drag` variable with `Boole[¬CurrentValue["ShiftKey"]]`, which then disables the polygon dragging behavior if the shift key is pressed. Locator dragging can then proceed as normal.

Comment: Disabling, of course! - Thank you very much, Sjoerd for the  excellent explanation.

Comment: What do I have to press to drag the polygon?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nothing. Just click-and-drag inside the polygon.

Comment: In that case this fails on v7, unlike Heike's answer referenced in the question.

Comment: Actually, for me the polygons move when using *right*-click-and-drag.  Is this expected?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, *I* didn't expect that, nor do I think my three modifications to Heike's code would cause that. I checked, but none of the functions involved seem to be upgraded in v8. Could you try removing the three additions from the code I posted and see what a drag-the-polygon does then? BTW you did click *inside* the polygon, didn't you?

Comment: "you did click inside the polygon" -- Yes.  Please post the version you would like me to test in Chat.